# MATLAB plot - use standard font and latex font in xlabel

Tags: matlab, plot, fonts, latex, axis-labels

When generating MATLAB plots, I use:

```
plot(x,y)
xlabel('$x$','Interpreter','Latex')
```

Then, x is displayed in the Latex font.

Now I want both, normal text and maths symbol as `xlabel`, say: time (*t*). So, the word `time` should be a standard font (say the MATLAB font when I don't use an interpreter) and the symbol `t` in brackets should be in the Latex font. But my attempts like:

```
xlabel('$\mathrm{time} (t)$','Interpreter','Latex')
xlabel('$\text{time} (t)$','Interpreter','Latex')
xlabel('time ($t$)','Interpreter','Latex')
```

all failed. Any ideas on how to mix the standard font with Latex font for `xlabel` in MATLAB?

Comment: With the `Tex`  interpreter you get all standard form but you can manually set variables in italic, use subindices etc: `xlabel('time ({\itx_{\rm1}})','Interpreter','Tex')`. Would that work for you?

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks for the input. It doesn't really imitate the standard latex font though does it? For instance, if you want a subscript, it's unnaturally low etc.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's a workaround, and the result is not very pretty. If the final purpose is to include the figure in a LaTeX document, have you considered [pstricks](https://www.ele.uri.edu/info/latex/psfrag/examp.pdf)? It's been long since I last used it, but I think it used LaTeX font for the replaced text only

Comment: [`matplotlib`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/matplotlib/info) has nothing to do here.

Comment: `xlabel('time({\fontname{mwa_cmr10}t})');` seems any better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard MATLAB font seems to be Arial, so when using the Latex interpreter I specified the text font with setting the x- and the y-labels as

```
xlabel('{\fontfamily{Arial}\selectfont Time} $t$', 'Interpreter',"latex");

ylabel('{\fontfamily{Arial}\selectfont Efficiency} $\varepsilon$', 'Interpreter',"latex");
```

Like this I can have the \varepsilon as well as the standard font.